# How to handle right-click "open in new tab" in EmberJs action?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, action, ember-cli

I have a link which calls an action on click like below. I haven't populated the href because I want this handled in the action and I don't want to trigger a page reload.

HBS

```
<a class="cursor-pointer" {{on "click" (fn this.goToPage this.nextPageNumber)}}>Next</a>
```

JS

```
@action
goToPage(pageName) {
  this.args.pageUpdated('page', pageName.toString());
  // scroll to top of search results
  document.querySelector('.search-summary-title').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Is there a way to direct the user to the right page if they right-click and choose "open in new tab"?

Answer (score 2):

what you should do is set the `href`:

```
<a href={{this.nextPageNumber}} {{on "click" (fn this.goToPage this.nextPageNumber)}}>Next</a>
```

and then prevent the default action in your `click` handler:

```js
@action
goToPage(pageName, event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.args.pageUpdated('page', pageName.toString());
  // scroll to top of search results
  document.querySelector('.search-summary-title').scrollIntoView();
}
```

this is also much better for accessibility!

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research I don't think this is possible to do within an action but I have a workaround if anyone is interested.

I don't want the href to interfere with my action so I don't want to populate it until I need it. So I've modified my template below, you'll see I've added another action which runs `oncontextmenu`. For those who don't know this event happens when the right click menu pops up.

HBS

```
<a href="#/" {{on "contextmenu" (fn this.setHref this.nextPageNumber)}} 
{{on "click" (fn this.goToPage this.nextPageNumber)}}>Next</a>
```

What I do now in the `setHref` action is just populate the href. Now when the user chooses New Window or New Tab it will go to the right place.
JS

```
@action
setHref(pageName, event) {
  event.target.setAttribute('href', `${window.location.pathname}?page=${pageName}`);
}
```

Comment: and why not just populate the `href`?

Comment: It will trigger a page transition which I don't want

Comment: You could prevent that by calling `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler if I didn't missed something.